# Unity3D Network ReadMessage

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

How to check the ERROR if the client is trying to connect to a absent server?

my code!

```
//Server 
void Start () { 
NetworkServer.Listen(13044);
}

//Client
NetworkClient thisclient = new NetworkClient ();
thisclient.Connect ("127.0.0.1", 13044);  
thisclient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Error, errortest);
thisclient.RegisterHandler (MsgType.Disconnect, dctest);  

void errortest(NetworkMessage netMsg){
var errorMsg = netMsg.ReadMessage<ErrorMessage>();  
Debug.Log("Error:" + errorMsg.errorCode);}  

void dctest(NetworkMessage netMsg){  
//if I run the client while the server is not present, its goes here instead of errortest 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using ReadMessage with ErrorMessage, but ErrorMessage is only valid in Error messages (OnError).

Your dctest function is triggered on disconnection, not on error.

Disconnect is a special MsgType (see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MsgType.html) that (if I remember) doesn't contain any data.

So to answer your question : you already have the result. Everything is in netMsg.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetMessages.html

The ReadMessage function is mostly used with your own NetworkMessages, when you wand to send/read custom data.

Comment: yes everything in netMsg. but i cant get the result of it. 

Debug.Log(netMsg) will not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "result" ?

Comment: I want to check if the client failed to connect in to the server, but I found out that this event will not call on MsgType.Error but instead in MsgType.Disconnect.

disconnecting and failed to connect is different but they are calling in just one function the Disconnect

 so if i used 

void onDisconnect(Networkmessage netmsg){
//netmsg message output here 
}

i want to get the "result" of netmsg if it's accepting the disconnect or the failed to connect.

and i want you to know that im using NetworkServer/Client RegisterHandler, is this recommended? or other alternatives?

Comment: NetworkServer/Client are ok to use. Please show more code, there is probably a problem in the way you're registering your messages. Show me how you initialize your server and your client and how your client is connecting.

Comment: `//Server <br/> void Start () { 
 NetworkServer.Listen(13044); } 
//Client 
 NetworkClient thisclient = new NetworkClient ();
thisclient.Connect ("127.0.0.1", 13044);
thisclient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Error, errortest); 
thisclient.RegisterHandler (MsgType.Disconnect, dctest); 
 void errortest(NetworkMessage netMsg){ 
 var errorMsg = netMsg.ReadMessage<ErrorMessage>(); 
Debug.Log("Error:" + errorMsg.errorCode);} 
 void dctest(NetworkMessage netMsg){
//if I run the client while the server is not present, its goes here instead of errortest }`

Comment: Edit your question to show this in code tags instead pls, hard to read :)

Comment: please check the new question thnx

Comment: Ok I understand better now. Your code is right, this is a bug in unity that should be fixed in version 5.5.0 : https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/networkclient-msgtype-dot-disconnect-is-returned-if-connections-times-out-when-connecting-to-non-existing-server so maybe you can update your editor ?

Comment: ok thnx, you said that there's no problem using networkserver/client registerhandler to communicate each other,

but this can help in my future plan in my program? which the server will create a room then the client will register to that room. wait the room to be filled then the server will start the game.

thnx best regards

Comment: hi FLX, I much appreciated your responses, I'm hoping that I have direct communication with you. I have many questions in my mind right now about this Unity/Unet. I hope that we can be close friends. ty

Comment: Hi FLX. the version of my Unity is 5.5.2f1. but the bug still exist.

Comment: Hi, what you call room is called lobby in Unity. You can read the doc about NetworkLobbyManager to know more. If you have more questions you can send me a private message on Unity forums (nickname: _FLX)